# SVG with transparent background, no css, svg file only

Tags: java, svg, batik

I need a svg file with transparent background.
In the following file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 600.00 400.00" >

<g><image id="SVGimage"  x="100" y="100" height="200" width="200"  xlink:href="../file.svg"/></g></svg>
```

So when the svg is applied to a colored canvas I could see the color of the canvas around the image.
I am not certain it is possible.

file.svg

```
 <svg id="Calque_1" data-name="Calque 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 128.06 158.68">
<g>
<defs>
<style>
.cls-1{fill:#faf7e8;stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:0.5px;}
.cls-2{fill:#353635;}
</style>
</defs>
<title>POISSON CHINOIS 50cm
</title>
<rect class="cls-1" x="0.25" y="0.25" width="127.56" height="127.56"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M348.24,268.22a50.81,50.81,0,0,1,0,6c-0.34,2.89-1,5.74-1.51,8.6-1,5.31-2,10.62-4.27,15.56-1.6,3.52-3.74,6.8-5.51,10.26-1.21,2.35-3.47,3.63-5.26,5.38a122.84,122.84,0,0,1-19,15.35c-4.62,3-9.74,4.7-15,6.1a51.51,51.51,0,0,1-16.1,1.4c-2.71-.15-5.37-0.87-8.07-1.2-4.69-.58-8.66-3-12.8-4.87a84.21,84.21,0,0,1-16.73-10.09,45.83,45.83,0,0,1-13.21-16.83,79.13,79.13,0,0,0-3.9-7.59A27.86,27.86,0,0,1,223,283.15c-0.28-4.46-.45-8.94-0.56-13.41-0.06-2.35.05-4.72,0.19-7.07a8.54,8.54,0,0,1,.65-2.29c1.65-4.59,3.09-9.27,5-13.74a52.56,52.56,0,0,1,12.41-18c5.75-5.31,11.68-10.38,19-13.5A66.87,66.87,0,0,1,270,211.78c5.44-1.33,11-1.47,16.62-1.66a54.92,54.92,0,0,1,21,3.75A51.32,51.32,0,0,1,327,226.45c1.31,1.37,2.81,2.57,4,4,3.8,4.56,7.88,9,10.57,14.25a106.56,106.56,0,0,1,6.19,14.7c0.91,2.73.61,5.85,0.85,8.79h-0.38Zm-63.92,28.6c6.84,2.41,13.53,2.92,20.35.34-1,2.71-1.25,5.2.53,7.66a5.16,5.16,0,0,0,2.16-5.72c1.44,2.18,3.26,3.42,6,3.19-0.3-3.41-2.52-5.13-5.44-6.36a5.34,5.34,0,0,1,1.38-.42,21.28,21.28,0,0,0,8.24-3.76c2.13-1.52,4.11-3.25,6.33-4.63,2-1.27,4.33-2.18,6.47-3.3a1.36,1.36,0,0,1,1.64,0,3.15,3.15,0,0,0,3.94-.32,8.94,8.94,0,0,1,8.66-1.79,6.68,6.68,0,0,0,.86.15l0.46-.56c-0.52-.31-1-0.64-1.55-0.92-2.37-1.23-4.76-1.62-7.18-.09a5.39,5.39,0,0,1-1.48.82c-1.26.31-2.48,1.28-4,.46A5.71,5.71,0,0,1,332,281c1.36-1.72,2.82-3.38,4.06-5.18a3.39,3.39,0,0,0-1.42-5.08l-1.31-.69a2.27,2.27,0,0,1,3-.55,5.54,5.54,0,0,0,4.12.5c2.8-.72,3.88-2.85,4.61-5.25a16.76,16.76,0,0,0,.36-2.49c-1.34,1.59-2.37,3-3.62,4.24s-2.76,2-4.53,1.32a4.83,4.83,0,0,0-4.91.73,1.06,1.06,0,0,1-1.64-.2,51.33,51.33,0,0,0-5.34-4.88,14.74,14.74,0,0,0-8.46-3.3,1.7,1.7,0,0,1-1.27-.79,10.85,10.85,0,0,0-5.75-5.77,4.46,4.46,0,0,1-2.39-2.74c-1.16-3.24-4.06-5.48-8.34-6.66a44.65,44.65,0,0,1,2.93,4.18,5.59,5.59,0,0,1,.27,4.82,14.76,14.76,0,0,0-4.51-6.14,10.71,10.71,0,0,0-7.26-2.41c3,2.14,6.49,3.85,6.93,8.3a4.83,4.83,0,0,1-1.52-.3,33.21,33.21,0,0,1-4-2.74c-2.15-1.85-4.39-3.36-7.42-3a18.32,18.32,0,0,0-2.08.48c3.2,1.13,5.95,2.51,7.86,5.4-2.06.46-3.77,0.56-5.31-.75a11.82,11.82,0,0,0-2.26-1.43,4.6,4.6,0,0,0-4.08.14,8.88,8.88,0,0,0,1.08.71,15.72,15.72,0,0,1,2.57,2.12c0.82,1,.37,1.72-0.94,1.76a2.28,2.28,0,0,1-1.13-.34,10.23,10.23,0,0,0-6.25-1.23,8.93,8.93,0,0,0-1.94.63l0,0.33c1.82,0.31,3.56.74,4.08,2.72a20.48,20.48,0,0,0-4.5-.37,6.54,6.54,0,0,0-4.14,2.33c2,0.23,3.83.43,4.39,2.5a48.6,48.6,0,0,0-5.8,1.34,45.8,45.8,0,0,0-5.2,2.58l0.15,0.4c0.55,0,1.1.07,1.65,0.16a8,8,0,0,1,1.66.38c1.77,0.69,2.15,1.13,1.09,3.22a12.48,12.48,0,0,1-4.78,4.85c-2,1.25-4.16,2.48-6.63,1.78a34.51,34.51,0,0,1-6.08-2.45c-2.66-1.35-5-3.37-8-4s-6.25-1.8-9.61-1a15.84,15.84,0,0,0-5.61,2.37c0.63,0.16,1.23.14,1.82,0.23,2.22,0.36,4.65.29,6.11,2.43a6.54,6.54,0,0,0,5.19,2.71,2,2,0,0,1,1.29.78c1.3,2,2.78,2.69,5.17,2.1a1.53,1.53,0,0,1,1.89.57,4.07,4.07,0,0,0,3.68,1.75c1.26-.06,2.5-0.28,3.76-0.34a2.15,2.15,0,0,1,1,.4c-0.4,1.4,1.56,3.32-.93,4.28a1.06,1.06,0,0,0-.44.69,26.94,26.94,0,0,0-.65,3.14,1,1,0,0,1-1.06,1.15c-1.47,0-2.1.92-2.68,2.06a3.71,3.71,0,0,1-1.47,1.65,14.18,14.18,0,0,1-3.67,1.15c-1.48.25-3,.25-4.51,0.35a6.07,6.07,0,0,0,2.52,2,41.28,41.28,0,0,0,6.71,1.12,4.08,4.08,0,0,0,2.54-1,25.62,25.62,0,0,0,3.87-3.64,13.87,13.87,0,0,1,6.31-4.47,12.19,12.19,0,0,1,7.19-.28,76.07,76.07,0,0,1,7.84,2.63,36.38,36.38,0,0,1,3.78,2c-3.41,1.34-4.41,3.68-4,7,2.44-1,3.89-2.77,5.24-4.86-0.39,2.76,1.18,4.49,2.83,6.26C285.49,301.48,285.51,300.63,284.32,296.82Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M279.58,269.84v3.38l-5.49.94c0.49-.69.82-1.18,1.18-1.66s0.48-.89-0.21-1.25a13.93,13.93,0,0,1-1.5-1c-0.85,1.19-1.95,2.66-2.94,4.19a4.85,4.85,0,0,1-2.82,2.1c-1.35.41-2.64,1-4,1.54a14.31,14.31,0,0,1-1.65.38,3.5,3.5,0,0,1,.53-0.89q2.29-1.68,4.61-3.31a9.79,9.79,0,0,0,4-5.15l-0.3-.28-2.89,2.83-0.34-.22a25.4,25.4,0,0,1,2.67-4.35,25.83,25.83,0,0,1,11-7.23c2.31-.75,4.55-1.74,6.89-2.33,2.89-.73,4-0.84,5.72,2,0.88,1.43,1.62,2.94,2.44,4.41,0.46,0.81.31,1.26-.66,1.58a2.28,2.28,0,0,1-2.72-.51,13.32,13.32,0,0,0-2.82-1.64,16.76,16.76,0,0,1,.26,3.21,17.47,17.47,0,0,1-1,3.13c-1.12-1.51-2.31-1.5-3.8-.87l0.38-4.47-3.63-.31c0.15,0.7.29,1.38,0.43,2.06a13.89,13.89,0,0,1,.35,1.76c0.16,2.15-1,2.93-3.11,2.07A3.62,3.62,0,0,0,279.58,269.84Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M299.29,264.44c0.14-.44.27-0.89,0.42-1.33a2.6,2.6,0,0,0-1-3.38c-1.2-.93-2.46-1.79-4-2.89a11.17,11.17,0,0,1,1.82-.21A62.57,62.57,0,0,1,311,259.14a23.1,23.1,0,0,1,2.72,1.26c-0.92.56-1.55,0.89-2.13,1.3-2.54,1.85-3.77,4.53-4.77,7.35a2.69,2.69,0,0,1-.58,1.15,9.53,9.53,0,0,0-3.12,5.79,3.58,3.58,0,0,1-.37.84l-2.66-.82,2-2.58c-1-.62-1.93-1.22-2.89-1.7a1.79,1.79,0,0,0-1.17.06,13.09,13.09,0,0,0-1.92.77c-0.53.26-1,.45-1.3-0.24s0.43-.82.88-1a12.1,12.1,0,0,1,6.11-.74,6.49,6.49,0,0,0,1.06,0,14.35,14.35,0,0,0-1-1.79,1,1,0,0,1,.29-1.7c0.85-.55,1.73-1,2.6-1.54,0.31-.17.64-0.3,1-0.49-0.43-.36-0.79-0.62-1.09-0.93-1.33-1.35-1.32-1.36-3.06-.48l-2,1Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M291.75,287.93l0.65,0.71c2.5,0.19,4.76.25,6.32,2.28l3.45-4.58,0.42,0.25a7.33,7.33,0,0,1-2.08,6.61,11.72,11.72,0,0,1-9.91,3.32c-1.15-.12-1.73-0.51-1.54-1.81a14.41,14.41,0,0,0-.18-2.84A1.45,1.45,0,0,1,289,291C289.81,290,290.73,289,291.75,287.93Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M312.33,271.34c0-3.73,1.31-5.77,4.75-6.74,2.5-.7,4.62.24,6.46,1.89a8.39,8.39,0,0,1,1,1.08c0.32,0.41,1,.87.22,1.35a1.17,1.17,0,0,1-1.78-.25,4.9,4.9,0,0,0-6.3-1.21c-2.6,1.53-2,5.7.19,7,3,1.84,5.46.88,6.59-2.52a2.6,2.6,0,0,1,.28-1,3.06,3.06,0,0,1,1.33-.61,1.1,1.1,0,0,1,.5.77c-0.25,2.55-1.4,5.58-4.53,6.45A6.79,6.79,0,0,1,312.33,271.34Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M293,277.34a2.16,2.16,0,0,1-1.13,2.88,2,2,0,0,0-1.24,2q0.12,2.08.14,4.17a1.76,1.76,0,0,1-.29,1,9.11,9.11,0,0,1-1,1.16c-0.52.53-1,1.31-1.92,0.69s-2-1-1.44-2.48,0.57-3,.94-4.55a12.32,12.32,0,0,1,.92-2.08,3.39,3.39,0,0,0-4.57-1.34,1,1,0,0,1,1-1.32c1.5-.07,3-0.08,4.5-0.1S291.61,277.34,293,277.34Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M276.39,279.78l4.42-1a9.33,9.33,0,0,0-.38.93,26.5,26.5,0,0,0-1.2,4.46c-0.26,2.51-.13,2.52-2.61,2.63-0.19,0-.38.05-0.58,0.08,0.36,1.67.56,1.75,4,1.71-1,.89-1.93,1.79-2.91,2.65a0.69,0.69,0,0,1-.58,0c-1.34-.55-2.68-1.12-4-1.69a1.57,1.57,0,0,1,.2-0.66c1.38-1,1.32-2.58,1.66-4A23,23,0,0,1,276,281.1,9.51,9.51,0,0,0,276.39,279.78Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M278.54,292.2l3.86-3.63a0.73,0.73,0,0,1,1.3.13c1.17,2,2.34,4.08,3.45,6.16,0.36,0.68-.15.91-0.73,0.75A31.3,31.3,0,0,1,278.54,292.2Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M306,272.49c0,7.86,4,12.28,12,13.22-2.54,1.7-7.55.22-10.05-2.86S304,274.74,306,272.49Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M284.31,275.43a5.32,5.32,0,0,1,1-.83,4.09,4.09,0,0,1,1.3-.28,1.35,1.35,0,0,0,1.42-1.28,2,2,0,0,1,2.18-1.85,4.33,4.33,0,0,1,2.78,1.13c0.5,0.65.2,1.89,0.21,2.87a0.72,0.72,0,0,1-.58.25c-2.36-1-4.65.13-7,.21-0.39,0-.77.08-1.16,0.12Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M258.59,281.36c3.07,0.92,5.13-1,7.48-1.8,0.3-.1.59-0.26,0.89-0.38a1.46,1.46,0,0,1,.44.12,15.46,15.46,0,0,1-1.82,2.2,48.5,48.5,0,0,1-4.52,3.4c-1.16.76-1.63,0.5-1.94-.82C258.93,283.23,258.78,282.35,258.59,281.36Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M283,275.38a3.2,3.2,0,0,1-.84.9,20.29,20.29,0,0,1-4.86,1.46c-2,.15-3.82.67-5.73,1a2.58,2.58,0,0,1-.74-0.13,2.68,2.68,0,0,1,1.95-1.87c2.11-.58,4.21-1.18,6.33-1.74a2.46,2.46,0,0,1,.88,0Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M316,288.62c-2.2,2.67-10.48-.12-12-3.29,1.31-1.34,1.47-1.27,2.63.07,2,2.32,4.75,3.08,7.73,3.22C314.83,288.64,315.33,288.62,316,288.62Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M267.74,282c-0.63,1.89-1.18,3.67-1.85,5.4a1.4,1.4,0,0,1-1.05.76,5.13,5.13,0,0,1-3.86-1.81Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M300.39,266.12c-1.06,1.62-1.7,3.12-3.68,3.36-1.5.18-3,.62-4.81,1a27.32,27.32,0,0,1,1.12-2.81,1.11,1.11,0,0,1,1-.09,1.61,1.61,0,0,0,1.9.17c1-.42,1.93-0.82,2.91-1.2C299.26,266.41,299.68,266.32,300.39,266.12Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M303.23,281.11a3,3,0,0,1-.9-0.53c-0.8-1.47-2.08-1.21-3.41-1-1.55.22-3.13,0.33-4.7,0.49,0-1.77,0-1.8,1.51-1.54a8.21,8.21,0,0,0,1.82,0c1.37-.08,2.74-0.16,4.11-0.26,0.84-.06,1.31.18,1.27,1.13A9.31,9.31,0,0,0,303.23,281.11Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M322,271a1.61,1.61,0,0,1-1.68,1.78,2.13,2.13,0,0,1-2.08-2.21,1.43,1.43,0,0,1,1.72-1.41C321.24,269.18,322,269.84,322,271Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M270.28,286.89l0.21,1.66-3.43-.36,1.72-3.13,3,0.13C272,286.8,271.73,287.06,270.28,286.89Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M299,273.78c-0.62,3-1.36,3.55-4,3.2l0.13-2.33Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M327,272.09a1.43,1.43,0,0,1,1.66-1.47,1.66,1.66,0,0,1,1.66,1.7,1.69,1.69,0,0,1-1.69,1.53A1.77,1.77,0,0,1,327,272.09Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M302.07,283.14c-0.63.67-1.06,1.16-1.51,1.61-0.63.61-1.12,0.45-1.55-.26a13.2,13.2,0,0,0-1-1.27l-0.29.14,0.12-1.54A9.08,9.08,0,0,1,302.07,283.14Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M331.91,279.13a2.7,2.7,0,0,1-.63-3.08c0.4-1.15.81-2.31,1.26-3.61a3.48,3.48,0,0,1,.75,1.29,6,6,0,0,1-.27,2.21C332.75,277,332.34,277.94,331.91,279.13Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M329.93,274.66a5.57,5.57,0,0,0-.69,5.42,1.8,1.8,0,0,1-1.93-1.77A3.39,3.39,0,0,1,329.93,274.66Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M297.58,285l2,1.29c-0.46.45-.93,1.27-1.38,1.26a2.51,2.51,0,0,1-1.73-1.08A1.16,1.16,0,0,1,297.58,285Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M285.09,279.65c0.23,1-.06,1.56-1.15,1.57a8.78,8.78,0,0,1-1.32,0,4.77,4.77,0,0,1-1.07-.44,3,3,0,0,1,1-1.11A11.93,11.93,0,0,1,285.09,279.65Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M284.2,287.22c-1.11-.67-1.85-1.67-3.1-1.23a0.84,0.84,0,0,1-.36-0.47,1.15,1.15,0,0,1,.6-0.62,12.7,12.7,0,0,1,2.55-.1,1.06,1.06,0,0,1,.62.79A6.58,6.58,0,0,1,284.2,287.22Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M283,282.46a3.86,3.86,0,0,1,1.08,0,2.56,2.56,0,0,1,.76.54,1.81,1.81,0,0,1-.63.68,16.38,16.38,0,0,1-2.65.14,0.8,0.8,0,0,1-.55-0.54,1,1,0,0,1,.55-0.72,6,6,0,0,1,1.44,0v0Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M292.7,282.28l3.17-.35c-0.21.62-.25,1.37-0.55,1.49a5.14,5.14,0,0,1-2.24.26A4.34,4.34,0,0,1,292.7,282.28Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M270.07,280.32l3.06-.52c0.32,1.18.19,1.36-1,1.35-0.36,0-.71.14-1.07,0.16a1.6,1.6,0,0,1-1-.08A1.71,1.71,0,0,1,270.07,280.32Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M269.27,284.08l0.23-1.25a18.65,18.65,0,0,1,1.9-.21,4.35,4.35,0,0,1,1.06.25,2.48,2.48,0,0,1-.76,1A12.49,12.49,0,0,1,269.27,284.08Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M287.29,270.75c-0.62.92-.41,2.44-2.15,2.07C284.88,271,285.27,270.59,287.29,270.75Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M293,285c0.58,0.73,2.25-.6,2.17,1.11,0,0.92-.84.74-1.49,0.65C292.48,286.57,292.76,285.8,293,285Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
<path class="cls-2" d="M283.33,271.38c-0.15.93,0.26,2.07-1.28,2.08C281.5,271.77,281.74,271.34,283.33,271.38Z" transform="translate(-222.27 -209.5)"/>
</g></svg>
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to contain a [mcve]. At the moment file.svg is missing.

Comment: Why do you think it isn't? Your posted code does not give any indication it is anything but.

Comment: Where do you recommend that I put code to express a transparent background in the master file? I want the viewport to be transparent. I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: You are not drawing anything in the SVG viewport but that inner image. Everything else _is_ transparent. The only way to make it opaque would be if that `<svg>` element was selected by a CSS rule that set a `background`. Avoid it, and it you are done.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am using SVG on a Java Swing context and drawing the SVG on a GlassPane and I expect to see through the GlassPane around the inner image, but always get this white background in the way. You are suggesting to use a CSS connected to the SVG. I did not know it was possible, but found in another Stackoverflow chat "Use CSS in Java Applications". I am going to give it a try and come back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a transparent background for and SVG file, I mean the root of the file to be transparent, one must use JavaFX with CSS. It seems that there is no way to do it with Swing only.